# Postcode vs Longitude and Latitude

Tags: php, computer-science

I'm trying to find research or information as to whether searching for a location by postcode in a web system is more accurate that longitude and latitude values. I am trying to justify why I have chosen the postcode method instead of the longitude and latitude values, or research/information backing up that statement.

I can't seem to find a lot of information regarding it.

Comment: lat, long is an exact point, postcode is an area

Comment: Most human beings (who might enter such data in a web form) are likely to know their postcode.... how many could tell you the latitude/longitude of an address as accurately?

Answer (score 2):

Latitude and longitude, with enough precision, can point to any place on Earth, including places outside national boundaries that have no postal codes.  Postal codes, on the other hand, are arbitrary boundaries that are unlikely to be available in, say, Antarctica or the Indian Ocean.  You use postal codes because most people are familiar with their local postal codes and can fill them into a form, where they probably can't tell you what their local lat/long coordinates are without tools - and those tools may require them to be able to read a map, which some people can't do very well.

Comment: In addition to this answer - in an event when my app isn't able to pinpoint the exact location by postal code/zip, then it'll use as an alternative fallback to curl to www.geoname.org via api to fetch longitude/latitude of the postal code/zip.  But, yes, longitude and latitude is much more accurate.